# Starting python script without installing dependencies

Tags: python

I have a python gui script and I'd like to send it to my colleagues without them needing to install anything. Is that possible?
I was thinking about packaging it and they'll just need to install python.
I'd like to make it for them as easy as as it is possible to.
They'll just click main.py and it will work for them.
I am using request and those need to be installed before starting the gui. Will the script work if I package it and they will open it without installing requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you might want to try is using PyInstaller to create an .exe file from the python script.

Here is a reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/